# reset <p:selectBooleanCheckbox> on page load

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to reset  on page load? Using JSF or onClick event of a CommandButton

Please post here an example either in Javascript or Ajax

Please some one help me for this issue

JSF Code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:commandButton value="Assign Permission"
        onclick="assignPermissionDlg.show()"></p:commandButton>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="assignPermissionDlg" width="75%">
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel>
                <p:dataTable value="#{mainBean.list}" var="perm" id="tableId">

                    <p:column headerText="Module Description:">
                        <h:outputText value="#{perm.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="View">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="view" value="#{perm.view}" >

                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Create">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="create" value="#{perm.create}">

                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Edit">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="edit" value="#{perm.edit}">

                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Delete">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="delete" value="#{perm.delete}">

                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
                <p:toolbar>
                    <p:toolbarGroup>
                        <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                            action="#{mainBean.confirmMethod}">

                            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?"
                                icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                        </p:commandButton>


                    </p:toolbarGroup>
                </p:toolbar>
                <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade"
                    hideEffect="explode">
                    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
                        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                        styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:tableId'))
                            .on(
                                    "change",
                                    "input[type='checkbox'][name*='edit'], input[type='checkbox'][name*='create'], input[type='checkbox'][name*='delete']",
                                    function() {
                                        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                                        var view = tr
                                                .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='view']");
                                        var create = tr
                                                .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='create']");
                                        var edit = tr
                                                .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='edit']");
                                        var deleteBox = tr
                                                .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='delete']");
                                        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                            view.prop("checked", true);
                                        } else {
                                            if (create.is(':checked') || edit.is(':checked')
                                                    || deleteBox.is(':checked')) {
                                                view.prop("checked", true);
                                            } else
                                                view.prop("checked", false);
                                        }
                                    });

                    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:tableId')).on(
                            "change",
                            "input[type='checkbox'][name*='view']",
                            function() {
                                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                                var view = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='view']");
                                var create = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='create']");
                                var edit = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='edit']");
                                var deleteBox = tr
                                        .find("input[type='checkbox'][name*='delete']");
                                if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) {
                                    create.prop("checked", false);
                                    edit.prop("checked", false);
                                    deleteBox.prop("checked", false);
                                }
                            });
                })


                </script>


</h:body>
</html>
```

Bean Code here

```
public class UserPojo {

    private String name;
    private Boolean view;
    private Boolean create;
    private Boolean edit;
    private Boolean delete;

    public Boolean getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(Boolean view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public Boolean getCreate() {
        return create;
    }

    public void setCreate(Boolean create) {
        this.create = create;
    }

    public Boolean getEdit() {
        return edit;
    }

    public void setEdit(Boolean edit) {
        this.edit = edit;
    }

    public Boolean getDelete() {
        return delete;
    }

    public void setDelete(Boolean delete) {
        this.delete = delete;
    }

    public UserPojo() {

    }

    public UserPojo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Finally code below

```
import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class MainBean implements Serializable{


        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1245080637297904760L;
        private List<UserPojo> list;

        public MainBean() {
              fillList();
        }

        public List<UserPojo> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(List<UserPojo> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public void fillList() {
            list = new ArrayList<UserPojo>();
            list.add(new UserPojo("Jack"));
            list.add(new UserPojo("Jhon"));
            list.add(new UserPojo("Smack"));
            list.add(new UserPojo("Jimmy"));
            list.add(new UserPojo("Dummu"));
            list.add(new UserPojo("Stakr"));
            list.add(new UserPojo("Simi"));
        }

        public void confirmMethod()
        {
            System.out.println("Save values in DB****************");
            for(UserPojo ul : list)
            {
                System.out.println("insert statement");



            }
        }

    }

Please help me to solve my issue Thanks
```

Comment: I'm try to post my code but its showing error msg only, saying that contains code only add more commands.if you can help me to my post code

Comment: Just copy paste your code in your question.

Comment: please see the attached code for your ref

Comment: have you tried `Request Scope`? place Request scope annotation on `RoleModule` managed bean

Comment: tried but not getting expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want to achieve then it's pretty much simple...

first set dialog ID

```
 <p:dialog id="assignPermissionDlgId" widgetVar="assignPermissionDlg" width="75%">
```

then alter your button to this

```
<p:commandButton value="Assign Permission" update=":assignPermissionDlgId"
    oncomplete="assignPermissionDlg.show()"></p:commandButton>
```

I think that each time you are opening the dialog you are seeing the previous checkboxes selected, in this way you update the dialog before you show it, the update cause the re-rendering.

But I can't see where you are saving the checkboxes values !
Note: If you have values in checkboxes the answer would be different.....

Comment: I'm saving the checkbox values in database. Next opening time I'm getting same previouse  value again without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the value of the checkbox in the constructor.

This is how your checkbox might look:

```
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{BeanClass.value1}" > </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

When the checkbox is checked, value1 becomes true. In the constructor of the bean class, you make value1 false.

You bean class:

```
    Class BeanClass
    {

        private boolean value1;
        public BeanClass()
        {
            value1 = false;
            //Someother statements might follow.
        }

        public boolean getValue1()
        {
            return value1;
        }

        public void setValue1(boolean value1)
        {
            this.value1 = value1;
        }
    }
```

Notice that I have set the value of value1 to false in the constructor, which gets called on page load, thereby rendering false in the primeface tag.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Why don't you post your jsf and bean code here? I can have a better look.

Comment: @PLanka why are you sure the entire bean will be reconstructed for setting `false` to the value? That could work for `@RequestScoped`, maybe not for the rest of the scopes!